# How to cast from Object 1 to Object 2 in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

How can I cast an Object to Person to access its property something like

```
((Person)self.dataObject).firstName;
```

except that clang doesn't accept this syntax :

DataViewController.h

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.dataLabel.text = ((Person)self.dataObject).firstName;
}
```

DataViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DataViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dataLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id dataObject;

@end
```

Person.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject

@property NSString* firstName;
@property NSString* lastName;

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not casting it as a pointer to an object. Instead you should be casting it as follows:

```
((Person *)self.dataObject).firstName;
```

Comment: The lack of the asterisk does not make a type "primitive". Pointers, in fact, are primitive types themselves, but objects, which are not, are only accessed via pointers in ObjC.